# Mongoose.connect() fails when database is specified in connection string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm running a local MongoDB server and am trying to connect to it from a node.js server using the Mongoose library.

I'm using SCRAM-SHA-1 as the authentication mechanism

I'm able to connect to it with the admin account when I don't specify a database to connect to, using a connection string such as:

```
mongodb://{username}:{password}@{address}:{port}?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
```

But when I try to specify which database to connect to, using a connection string such as:

```
mongodb://{username}:{password}@{address}:{port}/database123?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
```

the authentication fails.

For reference, my code looks like:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    let conn_string = `mongodb://mongo_uname:mongo_pass@192.168.1.1:3000/database123?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256`

    mongoose
    .connect(database_uri, {
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB database Connected...'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Is there a different way to specify which database to connect to with mongoose, or is there something I can do differently when constructing the connection string to make it work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error ended up being in the configuration of the database user I was trying to connect with, they weren't even set up to read or write to the database I was attempting to connect to.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the database user you are using is configured to read and write to the database uou are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongoose v6+, you should **NOT** specify `useUnifiedTopology`.

That is deprecated and if you include it, Mongoose will throw the error. Try to include the connection string only:

```js
mongoose.connect(database_uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mongoDB = "mongodb://localhost:27017/twlight";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => {
  console.log("Database is connected");
},
(err) => {
console.log("There is problem while connecting database " + err);
});
```

Please try

**Note: twilight is database name**